# How are Server Sent Events considered not client triggered through @GET

Tags: java, html, server-sent-events

Regarding Server Sent events, I am still a little fuzzy about one thing that I cannot seem to understand.  From all the Java demo code I have been finding on the web, all the server-side 'smarts' code seems to be in the @GET method.  The actions are performed there and results to the client are pushed there. So it seems to me as if the client has to perform a GET request first.  For some reason I cannot find this explanation anywhere, possibly because I should know this. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Server-sent events are indeed initiated by a first GET by the client; but then, the server gets to decide when events are sent without the client explicitly polling for them.

Comment: is the first GET "called" by the browser when a `new EvenSource` is created?  That would be handy.  My issue is I need no human interaction.

Comment: I guess what I'm really asking is - is the server supposed to store off the individual HttpRequests so that it can send updates to the clients as they come in?